# Apache reverse proxy based on header

Tags: reverse-proxy, redirect, rewrite, apache2

So I have a configuration for apache that is working in 99% of the cases.
It is checking a header value in the request and based on that it is redirecting to the correct API version url with a `307` status.
This works for all clients that properly implement the http stack. unfortunately I have an app that doesn't follow this and converts all `POST` requests into `GET`.

So this is the `proxy.conf` that I got right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Android-Version} =660
RewriteRule ^/services/6/(.*)$ /services/internal/6/$1 [R=307]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Android-Version} >661
RewriteRule ^/services/6/(.*)$ /services/internal/7/$1 [R=307]


ProxyPass /services/internal/7 http://mbe700:8080/services/6
ProxyPass /services/internal/6 http://mbe600:8080/services/6
```

So what I am wondering is:

Is it possible to the same sort of proxypass without using a URL rewrite rule, since that doesn't really work in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was way easier than I imagined... just changing the flag on the rewriterule seems to have done the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Android-Version} =660
RewriteRule ^/services/6/(.*)$ /services/internal/6/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Android-Version} >661
RewriteRule ^/services/6/(.*)$ /services/internal/7/$1 [P]


ProxyPass /services/internal/7 http://mbe700:8080/services/6
ProxyPass /services/internal/6 http://mbe600:8080/services/6
```